# Scroll bar hiding element in Internet Explore 11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-11

I occurs an issue on Internet Explore 11, I am not able to click the element which is positioned fixed and right 0; scroll bar hiding the element.
i have used bootstrap framework. 
please suggest.[image]

```
.contact-btn{
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
    color: #ff0062;
    position: fixed;
    right:0;
}
```

Comment: Please add minimal HTML/CSS code that reproduces your issue.

Comment: It's working fine on all browser except Internet explore 11

Comment: How can I resolve your issue without reproducing it? Can you please enough code to reproduce your issue in stack snippet?

Comment: .contact-btn{
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
    color: #ff0062;
    position: fixed;
    right:0;
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can fix this issue by adding `@-ms-viewport{ width: auto !important; }` to your css file.

So the scrollbar will become transparent cause the content take the whole screen.